# What is this yellow star?

Tags: star, galaxy, identify-this-object

In NASAs's August 26 2022 [photo of NGC 1156](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/2022/hubble-views-a-galactic-marvel):

[image]

Does anyone know what the incredibly bright yellow star is on the middle right?

**Bonus**: What's the bright (less bright than the yellow one) blue yellow star on the middle left?

Comment: I gave it a try with astrometry.net, but it failed to solve: https://nova.astrometry.net/status/6341906

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "incredibly bright" star is actually [TYC-1786-970-1](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=TYC%201786-970-1&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id), a 12th-magnitude star at a distance of 160 pc. From its colour I would say it looks like a late-G-type or early-K dwarf.

Bonus: The star appears to be Gaia EDR3 114923193014158592, but strangely it is not listed in SIMBAD. Its coordinates are approximately 02 59 41.7, +25 13 16 and it has a G magnitude of 14.7.

EDIT: As to how I found this out, I searched for "NGC 1156" in the [ALADIN Lite](https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/) catalog query and visualisation tool and ticked the box which marks on objects that are included in various catalogues.

Comment: You might want to use Stellarium.org to see where the star is in Aries.  The web version, doesn't seem to have it, either that or I couldn't find it.

Comment: One way to identify which ProfRob might've used is to use Stellarium and locate NGC 1156 and then zoom in to work out the nearest bright star near the NGC 1156.  Stellarium is a free application.

Comment: @DialFrost The link I provided DOES show an image of the area around the star. Though given that there is an image in your question I'm not sure why you need another.

Comment: @ProfRob Oh, sorry the image didnt load earlier, and it's because I wanted to see how the system identified it, but you already answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: How did you identify the color of the star?

Comment: @asdfex the linked SIMBAD entry gives $B-V =0.94$.